# Getting rid of "Tethering Detected" popup on Android ICS 4.0?

Tags: tethering

I just got a Samsung Galaxy S3 that runs Android ICS 4.0.8. When I connect the Galaxy S3 to my Mac laptop and use [PDAnet](http://junefabrics.com/android/) to tether, I often get this popup on the Galaxy S3 screen:

[image]

Tethering via PDAnet works great, but the popup can get annoying. I can close the popup, but it comes back a few seconds later. 
**How can I get rid of this popup permanently?**

Comment: I suspect its some crapware your provider put on there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This to me looks like something your provider has added in to stop you getting free tethering on your data plan.

If you are rooted (which I assume you are as you are using a tethering app), then you can attempt to freeze the app that is responsible for this, using an app freezer such as [App Quarantine ROOT](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ramdroid.appquarantine).

If it isn't an app, then it may be part of the ROM directly, in which case you would have to install a custom ROM such as CyanogenMod. You should look at forums such as [XDA-Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com) to find a ROM for your device.

Using a custom ROM will *definitely* remove the message.

Answer (score 2):

In the end, I rooted the phone and installed the [Cyanogenmod distribution](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/) in place of the cell phone carrier's OS. :)