# Three (UK telco provider) has blocked my tethering

Tags: tethering

I have a contract with Three (UK telco provider), which gives me unlimited data. My mobile is Samsung Galaxy S Plus (GT-I9001). Every time I try tethering, I get a pop up saying I can't tether. I have tried several apps but with no joy.

Does anyone know how to by pass Three finding out when I'm tethering?

Comment: @Yassar: I imagine that bypassing the tether block would be against their Terms of Service. Are you really asking us to abet you in violating your contract?

Answer (score 2):

Tethering on Three's (or most other UK telco providers) unlimited plans is against their terms and conditions.  You'll have to switch to a plan that allows tethering or use an add-on.  See [their Tethering info page](http://support.three.co.uk/SRVS/CGI-BIN/WEBISAPI.DLL?Command=New,Kb=Mobile,Ts=Mobile,T=Article,varset_cat=internetapps,varset_subcat=3582,Case=obj%283599%29) for more information.  Also see their [Terms and Conditions](http://www.three.co.uk/Privacy_Cookies/Terms_Conditions?content_aid=1214305745843)

However some phones will still allow you to tether, I'm surprised it doesn't work on the GS2.  Did you buy it from Three?  So the tether function still works, but when you do tether a Laptop, they send you a message?

Generally they detect mobile usage that comes from PCs and Laptops and then they ban you.  But tethering to other mobile devices seem to work, and also if you keep your data usage low, they may not bother.

Another possible work-around is to try and [spoof the user agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent#User_agent_spoofing) and trick Three into thinking that the data is being sent by a mobile device.  However, this is not fool-proof and they may still be able to detect, for example downloading a windows update.

**Just to be clear**, I would still recommend you buy an addon or join a different plan which *allows tethering*.  If you think the Terms and Conditions are unfair, file a complaint or switch telcos.

Update:

### Information on Three's **The One Plan**

> SIM plans with All-you-can-eat data do not allow tethering (except for the One Plan). If you would like to tether, you will need to choose a Pay Monthly plan and / or an Add-On that does allow tethering.

So it is possible to get the **One Plan**, for unlimited data *and* tethering.

And from [Tethering Explained](http://www.three.co.uk/Privacy_Cookies/Terms_Conditions?content_aid=1220469566802)

> If your smartphone plan includes all you can eat data, then this is for data consumption actually on your smartphone.  It does not include using your smartphone as a modem to connect other devices such as laptops and tablets – also known as “Tethering”.  Tethering is included in (i) The One Plan; (ii) the One Plan SIM only; or (iii) By purchasing an Ultimate Internet Plan with the Tethering Add on. The add-on can be purchased via My3 on your handset and is also available to customers on our Talk and Text plans.

See their [Pay Monthly plans](http://store.three.co.uk/view/searchTariff?deviceType=SIM_ONLY&priceplan=PAY_MONTHLY)

Comment: I bought the phone contract from a third party. Basically I'm asking for a way around it because as I have unlimited data I should be able to do what I like with it. As soon I connect it to my laptop I get a message from three :(

Comment: This is not correct, by signing up with them, you are agreeing with their [terms and conditions](http://www.three.co.uk/Privacy_Cookies/Terms_Conditions?content_aid=1214305745843) and when you break those terms and conditions, they have the right to ban you

Comment: On the contract it does not say you can not tether or that you can,so therefore technically ishould be able to if i choose to. I have not broken the tcs, iv asked to upgrade but they say i cant......

Comment: can you provide info on which contract/plan you are on

Comment: Unlimited data n tx and 900mins

Comment: are you getting this? http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36313/getting-rid-of-tethering-detected-popup-on-android-ics-4-0?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem with this app

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tetherunlocker

be careful to have only one apn for mobile traffic and remove the apn for tethering traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Just reset your phone. If the issue persists, call them.

Comment: It'd imagine it's not an 'issue', more that it's done deliberately on 3's part.